# Referencing Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.dll

Tags: c#

I've tried to reference the Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware in my project (both .Net 4 and 4.5), but I couldn't find it.

How can I find this DLL?

Comment: Shop for the hardware first.  http://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark_i2cspi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This DLL is only available with the [.Net Micro Framework](http://netmf.codeplex.com/) which is available for download [here](http://netmf.codeplex.com/releases/view/82448).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other library that will let me use SPI?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with C#. you would need a driver/kernel module for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the .NET Micro Framework.

I am 100% sure even if you could reference it, it will be of no use to you.